# How can I cast a struct reference to isize?

Tags: rust

I want to get `b` in the following code.

```
unsafe {
    struct Test {
        num: i32,
    }
    let a = Test { num: 0 };
    let b = &mut a as isize;
}
```

But it results in the following error message.

```
error: casting `&on_create::Test` as `isize` is invalid
   --> main.rs:181:15
    |
181 |       let b = &a as isize;
    |
```

I thought it would be coerced to `*const _`, then applied [ptr-addr-cast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html). What have I missed on this? Should I use `mem::transmute`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought it would be coerced to `*const _`, then applied ptr-addr-cast. ...

*Firstly*, implicit coercion doesn't happen everywhere, and certainly not inside part of an expression like `e as T` as you have noticed. The places where coercion happens, called [coercion sites](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html), are usually where you've done evaluating the expression, e.g.

- RHS of `let`/`const`/`static` statements:

  ```
  let x = foo
  //      ^~~
  ```
- Arguments to functions:

  ```
  foo(bar)
  //  ^~~
  ```
- Returned expressions:

  ```
  fn f() -> u32 {
      foo
  //  ^~~
  }
  ```
- struct/array/tuple literals:

  ```
     [foo, bar, baz]
  //  ^~~  ^~~  ^~~
     (foo, bar, baz)
  //  ^~~  ^~~  ^~~
     Foo { field: foo }
  //              ^~~
  ```
- Last expression in a block:

  ```
  { ...; foo }
  //     ^~~
  ```

`foo as isize` is not among this list.

*Secondly*, even if implicit coercion were allowed everywhere, that does not mean Rust should choose to coerce to a type that makes the conversion valid. An `&mut Test` can be coerced to `&Test` or `*mut Test` or `*const Test` or `&mut SomeTrait` etc, the compiler will need to check all of them! This can only work if *you* tell what type the expression should coerce to:

```
#![feature(type_ascription)]

let b = {&a}: *const _ as isize;
//       ^~ ^~~~~~~~~~
//        |   we explicitly make the type a const raw pointer
//        |                             using type-ascription
//        a coercion site
```

But this has not much of a difference than the canonical solution `&a as *const _ as isize`.

Comment: Finally I notice what I have missed, the coercion site. I'm fully satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use explicit conversion; "chains" of conversions / coercions don't usually (ever?) work:

```
struct Test {
    num: i32,
}
let a = Test { num: 0 };
let b = &a as *const _ as isize;
```

Since there's no reason for mutability, I've removed it. There's also no unsafe behavior in this code snippet, so the `unsafe` block is not needed.

Comment: Document says casting is not transitive, but applying ptr-addr-cast to above is why not the case? is `isize` not  numeric or is struct not `Sized`?

Comment: @jeiea I'm afraid I don't understand your question. `isize` is definitely numeric, and the struct is `Sized`. The problem is, as you said: *even if `e as U1 as U2` is a valid expression, `e as U2` is not necessarily so*.

Comment: I thought `&T to *const T` is applied implicitly because it is coercion and `as *const _` would be needless. But it seems coercion is not applied automatically. Is only final coercion implicit?