# Return type of .peekable() isn't Peekable<T>

Tags: types, rust

I'm trying to compile the following code with Rust version 1.22.1:

```
use std::str::Split;
use std::iter::Peekable;

// This is fine...
fn tokenize<'a>(code: &'a str) -> Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool> {
    code.split(char::is_whitespace)
}

// ...but this is not...
fn tokenize_peekable_bad<'a>(code: &'a str) -> Peekable<Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool>> {
    code.split(char::is_whitespace).peekable()
}

// ...however this is?
fn tokenize_peekable<'a>(code: &'a str) -> Peekable<Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool>> {
    tokenize(&code).peekable()
}
```

It seems to me that `tokenize_peekable_bad` and `tokenize_peekable` should have the exact same type signature, but `tokenize_peekable_bad` gives a compiler error while `tokenize_peekable` is just fine.

The error is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     code.split(char::is_whitespace).peekable()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
   |
   = note: expected type `std::iter::Peekable<std::str::Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool>>`
              found type `std::iter::Peekable<std::str::Split<'_, fn(char) -> bool {std::char::<impl char>::is_whitespace}>>`
```

Can someone explain this puzzling result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the function pointer from its specific concrete type to the non-specific function pointer type:

```
fn tokenize_peekable_ok_now<'a>(code: &'a str) -> Peekable<Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool>> {
    code.split(char::is_whitespace as fn(char) -> bool).peekable()
}
```

Your working solution automatically does this when you call the `tokenize` function because the number of steps the type system has to make is only one (`Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool {specific}>` -> `Split<'a, fn(char) -> bool>`). In `tokenize_peekable_bad`, it's already wrapped `Split` inside of `Peekable` by the time it checks the return type, so it doesn't know to flow the cast back to the original location. Specifically, it's not at a [*coercion site*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/coercions.html).

See also:

- [What is a function signature and type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42157511/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [How can I cast a struct reference to isize?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43418766/155423)